# How to write an eclipse plugin similar to exisiting Find/Replace dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to write an eclipse plugin that should work similar to the existing Find/Replace dialog. I.e. if I press a key combination of my choice when the focus is on an arbitrary text editor, a dialog I wrote should pop up and I would need a reference to an `IFindReplaceTarget` interface (or an `IFindReplaceTargetExtension3` interface ).
How is this possible? Which extension points do I need to extend?

The order in which I want to achieve things is

1) Make a dialog pop up on the press of a key combination ( there I must extend a certain extension point I don't know )

2) Maybe then I get the `IFindReplaceTarget` interface by getting the active editor and casting the active editor to this interface. In any case, I want an `IFindReplaceTarget` somehow.

3) It would also be great to be able to see the full source code of the plugin which contributes the Find/Replace dialog. I was able to open the dialog, set the focus on it, and then press Alt+Shift+F1 and access the source code of the `FindReplaceDialog` class. But how can I see source code of the whole plugin?

Comment: Just asking how to do this whole thing is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Ask more specific questions about the various aspects of this.

Comment: So I edited the question. I would be helped already if I could make a dialog pop up on the press of a certain key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point to define a command.

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point to define a handler for your command. The handler class can open your dialog.

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point to define a key binding for your command.

You can get the `IFindReplaceTarget` (if there is one) for the current part using something like:

```
IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().getActivePart();

IFindReplaceTarget target = (IFindReplaceTarget)part.getAdapter(IFindReplaceTarget.class);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the solution to my problem. I provided also a more detailed answer of what I achieved.

Comment: Do you accidently also know how I can see the source code of the plugin which contributes the Find/Replace dialog? See my edited post.

Comment: See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html The key points are you make sure you have the 'Eclipse SDK' installed and the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option selected.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin.xml file did the job

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="com.florian.regexfindandreplace.commands.FindAndReplaceCommand"
            name="FindAndReplaceCommand">
         <defaultHandler
               class="com.florian.regexfindandreplace.handlers.FindAndReplaceHandler">
            <parameter
                  name="com.florian.regexfindandreplace.parameter1"
                  value="com.florian.regexfindandreplace.parameter1">
            </parameter>
         </defaultHandler>
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="com.florian.regexfindandreplace.commands.FindAndReplaceCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+F5">
      </key>

       <scheme
  name="Default"
  description="Default shortcuts for Eclipse"
  id="default.id" />
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

In my handler I had to override execute, isEnabled and isHandled like this

```
@Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().getActivePart();

        IFindReplaceTarget target = (IFindReplaceTarget)part.getAdapter(IFindReplaceTarget.class);

        ExtendedFindReplaceDialog dialog = new ExtendedFindReplaceDialog(part.getSite().getShell(), target);
        dialog.setBlockOnOpen(true);
        dialog.open();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHandled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
```